# Keep helper text space active with Material UI Input disabled

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, user-experience

Is there a way to show the helper text space on a version 5 React Material UI Input on an input even when it’s disabled? Right now when the component is disabled, the helper text space goes away as well.

My use case is that when I’m in the view stage of my page, all of the inputs are disabled and then when I hit edit, this action adds the blank line of helper text which causes all of the inputs to jump as each one adds bottom padding. I’d like to avoid this jumping behavior if possible.

Comment: I don't think mui text field hides `helperText` according to the disabled or not, are you sure you're not passing undefined, null or empty string when it is disabled? Can you show a minimal example on https://codesandbox.io/ please?